# How to set sub-value of dynamically created expander in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, label, expander

I have a method that takes a ComboBoxItem Name and creates an expander with a header based on the name of that ComboBoxItem.  Shown below.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = combobox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
    if (selectedItem != null)
    {
        string name = selectedItem.Name;
        Expander expander = new Expander {Header = name};
    }
 }
```

I would like to then open a file dialog in order to select files and have the sub-value of the Expander set to the name of the file selected.  Code with file dialog combined with above code shown below.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender,   SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = combobox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
    if (selectedItem != null)
    {
        string name = selectedItem.Name;
        Expander expander = new Expander {Header = name};

        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".xlsm";
        dlg.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx) | *.xlsx";
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            //not sure what to do here, something like this maybe?
            //this.expander.?subvalue? = dlg.FileName;  
        }
    }
 }
```

I know I can use anything as the sub-value, like a label or anything, but I'm not sure how to attach that to the newly created expander.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand what you're looking for but there is no `SubValue` property for the expander. may be what you're looking for is the `Content` property.

```
this.expander.Content = new TextBlock(){Text=dlg.FileName};
```

Comment: Thanks, you did understand the question correctly.  That answer makes perfect sense.  For some reason I'm getting an error "'myProject.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'expander' and no extension method 'expander' etc..."  is that because x:Name does not exist for the dynamically created expanders?  If so, how could I set the name? I have the Header being set, but not sure how to syntactically add x:Name in this scenario.

Comment: that's because you need to keep track of the dynamically added expenders some where (in a global list variable  for example) and access them from there.